# How can I get all filter combinations and their links for all categories in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, url, filter, sitemaps

I have a problem and I do not know how to solve it. The client wants to get links of all filter combinations for the category, and make a check on index and follow. And if there is a parameter index and follow are true, then write it to the site map. Can you please tell me how to implement this task?